# PHP syntax error in most of scripts

Tags: php

i have copied and pasted an script from php.net website... Using an online free server always i try to test a php script i get syntax error...

For example with this simple code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ejemplo PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo '<p>Hola Mundo</p>'; ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/a2524311/public_html/test1.php on line 6
```

And this with a lot of tried scripts...

I think server uses PHP 5.2 but i am not sure

Comment: Can you post the whole code of test1.php? (Or did you already?)

Comment: I think you have more code in `test1.php`. [The output](http://3v4l.org/1qgG5) of the given php code is same from PHP 4.3 to 5.5-alpha.

Comment: Does a `phpinfo()` script work (as in: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in a php file, nothing else)

Comment: Does the host have any prepend script configured?

Comment: For all: that is the all code of test1.php also tried phpinfo() it didnt work... Also i have to say that i am using 000webhost.com

Comment: Select all. Copy. Open Notepad. Paste. Select all. Copy. Return to your PHP editor. Paste. Is it still broken?

Comment: Yes it is :( there must be something wrong with the server or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brother, I've run the script you gave. It's working perfectly fine. No Errors. Mine PHP version is 5.3.8. Try echoing phpinfo() to know about your PHP version.

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Hope that works for you. Thanks

Comment: It worked, it uses PHP version 5.2.17... But i still dont know why i get these errors :(

Comment: Don't echo phpinfo(); phpinfo() generates the output without it needing to be echoed; echoing as well will give you a spurious echo of the resulting true/false boolean

Comment: phpinfo() is just for your own sake. To get to know about your php parser and its relevant information. so that one can code accordingly. by the way brother Bams, did you tried running your code once again. is it working properly?

Comment: Yes it works, but why above poste script doesnt work for me???

Comment: It should work, as there is NO syntax errors in the code. please upload your file once again and try refreshing. I'm sure It'll work

Comment: yes bro, that's the phpinfo(); you're seeing. Please comment or remove that statement and try running your script as you've asked in the question. it should definetly work

Comment: @BamsBamx can you make a copy of `test2.php` and change its extension to `.txt`?

Comment: Brother Try Double quotes around the text to be displayed.

    <?php echo "<p>Hola Mundo</p>"; ?>

Comment: Tried double quotes, still the same.... And tried to rename with txt extension... now it doesnt appear anything.... Also i have watched that with print function it works well

Comment: http://www.myhomebnb.in/one.php . It is working fine on my server. There must be problem with your web-server. Please contact your server administrator and tell this PHP problem to him, there might be some modules displaced or missing from your server.

I shall deactivate the link in 5 minutes from now. just check it once and let me know. The code is same as the one you wrote in the question. Thank you.

Comment: Or there are some ["invisible" characters](http://xkcd.com/1137/) in the file.